# How to change the value of a JSON data while diplaying in a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, each, key-value

I am getting the data from the database as key value pairs and trying to populate the values in a list view. While looping I would like to change the value of a data (item.student_class) into 'Your next class is 2' if its value is class1. When I try it as below, it changes all the values in the list.

```
 var buffer="";

 $.each(data, function(index, val){ 

              for(var i=0; i < val.length; i++){ 

              var item = val[i]; 
//If the student's class is class1, change its value as below

   if(item.student_class= 'class1'){var studentclass='Your next class is 2';}

 buffer+='<li id="' + item.student_id+ '" data-student_class="'+studentclass+'"><a href="#"><b>' + item.student_name+'</b><span class="af-badge" style="background-color:#4a4">'+studentclass+'</span><br/>'+item.join_date+'</a></li>'; 
             } 
      $('#student_list').html(buffer); });
```

Could someone please help me how I can acheive it ?

Answer (score 1):

you are assigning a value, rather than comparing one , try as follows:

```
if(item.student_class== 'class1'){var studentclass='Your next class is 2';}
```

When you are assigning a value, it will work every time, and for that all of them will be changed. (probably you know, but it is common miss :-)

If you have multiple options, you can use the switch statement as follow:

```
var studentClass;
switch (item.student_class){
   case ('class1'):
     studentClass='Your next class is 2';
     break;
   case ('class2'):
     studentClass="Your next class is 3';
     break;
   default:
     studentClass= "Whatever should it be if nothing from cases apllies";
}

// Add rest of your code
```

Comment: That solved my problem. Can you show me how I can do switch statement instead of if condition ? as I have more than one value to change. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BigB - that is another question.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the conditional to not do an assignment.
You are initializing the variable inside the condition and thus it might be undefined in some cases.  Set it to "" first: i.e.

```
var buffer = "";
$.each(data, function (index, val) {
    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
        var studentclass = "";
        var item = val[i];
        //If the student's class is class1, change its value as below
        if (item.student_class == 'class1') {
            studentclass = 'Your next class is 2';
        }
        buffer += '<li id="' + item.student_id + '" data-student_class="' + studentclass + '"><a href="#"><b>' + item.student_name + '</b><span class="af-badge" style="background-color:#4a4">' + studentclass + '</span><br/>' + item.join_date + '</a></li>';
    }
    $('#student_list').html(buffer);
});
```

Comment: Just to note: the original code has a `$.each` with a for loop inside and for every `$.each` it will reset the value of `$('#student_list')` html to a new set - so probably needs to be evaluated for validity there.